# Angular 5 *ngFor filtered data length

Tags: angular

I have next ngFor repeat:

```
*ngFor="let item of items | filterBy: ['SN', 'Name']: userFilter | orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: 1}; let i = index;"
```

I need get Count of Filtered items. If I add let count = count, I will get only 10.

Comment: Do you use any custom pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<span>
   {{ (items | filterBy: ['SN', 'Name'])?.length }}
</span>
```

Comment: How can i add this value to the variable for using in several places? Example: I need hide some elements, if length = 0.

Comment: You can add it to a template variable like this: <div let-lenght="(items | filterBy: ['SN', 'Name'])?.length"> <ng-container *ngIf="length">TEST </ng-container></div>. have in main that if the variable is inside a *ngIf you can access to it from inside.